# Java import error - org.jdom

Tags: java, netbeans, importerror, file-structure

I am attempting to edit code from an old developer.
I know it is bad practice but what she said I had to do was create a dummy project and then copy paste the packages in question modify what I need to modify then compile and copy the classes that I changed into the directory where the classes in use are stored.

So I created the dummy project and copied the packages/files into the source folder of the dummy project but I keep getting a "package org.jdom does not exist" error.

The error appears on the lines:

```
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;
```

When I copied the folders/files into the source folder I copied the entire "org" directory. 
You can see from my screenshot that the package is in the Project Explorer 
[image: JDOM in Project Explorer]

I have several things to resolve the issue but none seemed to work. 
I tried adding the "org" directory into the classpath environment variables.
 
I tried adding the "org" directory as a library to the project. 
I have tried clearing the NetBeans cache after doing both of these but none of these 3 things worked. 
Below is a screenshot of the projects src folder in file explorer 
[image: File Explorer Screenshot]

**Can someone explain to me what I need to do to get this issue resolved?**

Comment: Try clean then build

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the wrong files to the libraries section of my project. 
I was adding the source for jdom when i should have been adding the jdom .jar file. 
Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

install jdom at your library folder, there is a new version of jdom try to download it and install it in your project directory.